# Authorizationcontext getting redirected URL from DNS lookup, not the actual visited URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter, antiforgerytoken

When I visit URL, in authorizationcontext (C# MVC OnAuthorization method) I'm getting redirected URL from DNS lookup, not the actual visited URL, Please guide why does it happen.

Example:

Suppose I've visited URL://www.myexample.com which has redirection to redirected.com, in the following code I should get visited URL ie myexample.com

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext actionContext)
{
    var x = actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;
}
```

but x has value redirected.com. When this happens and how to get it working.

This is happening randomly, sometimes it works for 30-40 mins without any change in code. My URL is hosted on App Service with all proper domain related settings.

I started getting this issue recently it was working fine for 2 months.